# Why do Lagrange multipliers work in mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I understand that it is not always simple to find generalized coordinates that satisfy the constraint equations, so we try to find an alternative (more mechanical) method that yields curves that satisfy said equations directly.

However, I do not understand how arbitrarily adding the Lagrange multipliers into the Lagrangian accomplishes this.

How can we ensure that the curves obtained will satisfy the constraints?
Why are the multipliers only assumed to depend on time?

Comment: This really comes down to understanding why Lagrange multipliers work at all, i.e. having nothing to do with physics. Have you studied the idea of Lagrange multipliers in a purely mathematical sense?

Comment: I have. Although I don't really see how both concepts relate.

Comment: Langrange multipliers are a mathematical technique used to find the extrema of a function under various constraints. The multipliers allow you to treat the problem as if it were unconstrained. In the mechanical case you're just extremizing the action, but the point of the Lagrange multipliers is exactly the same.

Comment: @DanielSank: sounds like you've got a start for an answer...

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, but I do need to refresh my own understanding before I can give a really good answer.